# How do I insert a new node into a empty list?

Tags: c

I'm trying to understand this code from Deitels 5th edition c book.

If I'm an inserting a new node in a linked list,  why am I setting a nextPtr = *sPtr. Shouldn't the first node have a nextPtr of NULL?

Also what does *sPtr = newPtr mean?

```
struct listNode {
   char data;
   struct listNode *nextPtr;
 };


void insert(ListNodePtr *sPtr, char value)
{

ListNodePtr newPtr; /* pointer to a new node */
ListNodePtr previousPtr;  /* pointer to a previous a node in list */
ListNodePtr currentPtr;  /* pointer to current node in list */

newPtr = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));  /* create node */

if (newPtr != NULL){ /* is space available */
    newPtr->data = value;
    newPtr->nextPtr = NULL;

    previousPtr = NULL;
    currentPtr = *sPtr;

    while (currentPtr != NULL && value > currentPtr->data){
        previousPtr = currentPtr;
        currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
    }

    /* insert new node at beginning of list */
    if (previousPtr == NULL){
        newPtr->nextPtr = *sPtr;
        *sPtr = newPtr;
    } else { /* insert new node between previosuPtr and currentPtr */
        previousPtr->nextPtr = newPtr;
        newPtr->nextPtr = currentPtr;
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first node shouldn't have it's `nextPtr` set to `NULL`, that would be the last node (afterall you need to be able to get from the first to the second node). The `nextPtr` of the first node points to the second node, which has a pointer to the third node and so on. So when you insert at the beginning of the list you let the `nextPtr` of the new node point to the old beginning of the list, which is `*sPtr`. Afterwards you set the pointer which points to the beginning of the list to point to the new node by doing `*sPtr=newPtr`.

Comment: I see. That is beginning to make sense.

Comment: @user995864: First of all I think that should be `(*sPtr)->nextPtr`, since `sPtr` is a pointer to a listpointer. If the new value was inserted at the beginning `(*sPtr)->nextPtr` will point to whatever `*sPtr` was before the insertion. For an empty list (*sPtr) will be `NULL` at the start of the insertion, so in that case `(*sPtr)->nextPtr` will be `NULL` afterwards.

Comment: Ok. I was thinking *sPtr had a value on an empty node list. Forgot that it was null on the first inserted value. That totally clarifies it! Thanks so much! Hate being a newb but I'm getting there ever so slowly!

Answer (score 1):

The new node is inserted at the beginning of the list, so next points to the beginning of the list, and the beginning of the list is set to point to the new node, for example:

if you have 
b->c

And you want to insert a, first make a point to b
a->b->c

then set list to point to a
list->a->b->c

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the line `newPtr->nextPtr = *sPtr` then this is code for the case where the new data value is less than anything already in the list, and the node must be inserted at the beginning. The new nodes `nextPtr` must point to what used to be the first node in the list (`newPtr->nextPtr = *sPtr`), and the beginning must change to the new node (`*sPtr = newPtr`). The code looks fine to me.